# How to center align the label text inside the option tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, label

I have the label text aligned in the left side and I would like to have it in the center. I've tried an id inside the option tag with "align text", "margin" and "padding" but it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<select id="primeiroselect"> 
  <option id="teste" label="Volvo">Volvo (Latin for "I roll")</option>
  <option label="Saab">Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)</option>
  <option label="Mercedes">Mercedes (Mercedes-Benz)</option>
  <option label="Audi">Audi (Auto Union Deutschland Ingolstadt)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is center for choosen value, add select tag style="text-align-last:center"

```
<select id="primeiroselect" style="text-align-last:center";> 
 <option id="teste" label="Volvo">Volvo (Latin for "I roll")</option>
  <option label="Saab" align="center">Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)</option>
  <option label="Mercedes">Mercedes (Mercedes-Benz)</option>
  <option label="Audi">Audi (Auto Union Deutschland Ingolstadt)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: great that worked and now I know why. Thanks a lot dude